# How to access outlets from UICollectionView to UICollectionReusableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

Registered header in ViewController:

```
self.itemCollectionView.register(NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView")
```

In the CollectionView Delegate Method:

```
extension UpcomingSubscriptionListViewController:  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let headerView = itemCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) as! NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView
    headerView.newSubscriptionRequestViewDelegate = self
    return headerView
}
```

My Header collection file

```
protocol NewSubscriptionRequestViewDelegate : class {

}

class NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

weak var newSubscriptionRequestViewDelegate:  NewSubscriptionRequestViewDelegate?
var contentView : NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let contents = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView
    contents.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    contents.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    self.addSubview(contents)
}

@IBOutlet var pdfStatus: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var nutritionView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var dateView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var nutritionPlanLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var calendarLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    dateView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    nutritionView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
}
```

I want to change the `pdfStatus` label from the `viewController` class but when I am trying to achieve through the following code. It's giving me `nil`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

   let headerView = itemCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) as! NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView
    headerView.newSubscriptionRequestViewDelegate = self
    headerView.pdfStatus.text = "something" .  // Getting nil here
    return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implement wrong methods when you register your reusableView. You need to register your reusableView using this method.

```swift
collectionView.register(UINib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:, withReuseIdentifier:)
```

Not

```swift
collectionView.register(Class, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:, withReuseIdentifier:)
```

If you don't register your XIB, UICollectionView don't have any data about IBOutlet(IBAction also). So Your cell can be created with a defined init method, but IBOutlet is nil.

So your code should be like

```swift
self.itemCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView", withReuseIdentifier: "NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView")
```

[registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618083-registernib?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks for replying but After replacing with `UINIB`. I am getting : `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader with identifier NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: @AmitPal How did you create your XIB? `File > New File > View(User Interface)` or `File > New File > Cocoa Touch Class`

Comment: One more thing, How did you set reuse Identifer for your ReusableView?

Comment: I used this code and it works for me :

` let headerNib = UINib.init(nibName: 'NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView', bundle: nil)
        itemCollectionView.register(headerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView")`

Just one more question. I can access the `label` inside `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind ` but what if I have to access the same label from another place

Comment: How about if I use `headerView.pdfStatus.text = "dadw"` at some other place whereas `headerview = NewSubscriptionRequestCollectionReusableView` and it's equivalent to `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind.header`

Comment: You should not set like that. The correct way is to define how the value of that label should change in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`. If you set a value for the label of the headerview elsewhere, the changed value is lost when the ReusableView is reused because of the UICollectionView's reuse system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199108/discussion-between-changnam-hong-and-amit-pal).